# Subclassing ndarray with attributes which update

Tags: python, numpy, subclassing

I would like to create instances of an object just like a `np.ndarray` but with the addition of the ability to call the method `apply_gain(gain)` which simply adds to the array, whilst also to calculate the mean as an attribute (`.dBFS`).

I have written an example of what I intend below, and it seems to produce the correct output. However when I use this in real world application, after many slices and operations, I occasionally get a discrepancy between `d.mean()` and `d.dBFS`.

EDIT: I have included an minimal example of the bug below. Whilst the following code runs correctly

```
class MyArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, inputarr):
        obj = np.asarray(inputarr).view(cls)
        obj.dBFS = obj.mean()
        return obj

    def apply_gain(self, gain):
        return self + gain 

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None: return
        self.dBFS = self.mean()

d=MyArray(np.array([1,2,3])) 
print(d[0:2].dBFS, d[0:2].mean())
>>>1.5 1.5 
print(d[0:2].apply_gain(2))
>>>[3,4]
```

The following code shows the bug:

```
import unittest

class MyArrayTestCase(unittest.TestCase):     


def test_a(self):
    d=MyArray(np.array([1,2,3])) 
    print(float((d[0:2]+d[0:2]).dBFS)) #print 3.0
    np.testing.assert_array_equal((d[0:2]+d[0:2]).dBFS, (np.array([1,2,3])[0:2]+np.array([1,2,3])[0:2]).mean())

def test_b(self):
    d=MyArray(np.array([1,2,3])) 
    print(float((d[0:2]+d[0:2]).dBFS)) # print3.5 
    np.testing.assert_array_equal((d[0:2]+d[0:2]).dBFS, (np.array([1,2,3])[0:2]+np.array([1,2,3])[0:2]).mean())

def test_add_2_gain_slice(self):
    d=MyArray(np.array([1,2,3])) 
    np.testing.assert_array_equal(d[0:2].apply_gain(2), np.array([1,2,3])[0:2]+2)
```

OUTPUTS
    ...3.0
    3.5

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.201s

OK
```

Note that the same function prints both 3.0 and 3.5. Removing test_add_2_gain_slice fixes this bug. I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Have you tried making `dBFS` a property rather than an attribute?

Comment: Thanks, please could you provide an example of what you mean? Note: I've added a minimal example of the bug

Comment: Your `dBFS` doesn't apply reliably with operators - any sum, difference, multiplication.  I've glanced at how subclasses like `matrix` and `MaskedArray` handle this, but not studied it.